# Unsupported Languages in Community Language Picker and Translation Workbench

Tags: community, translation, translation-workbench

How do you build a Community in a language that's not available in Translation Workbench or as a Community Language?

Is Salesforce able to add an option for my use-case if I create a ticket?

It seems strange to me that you can't create any language you want in the workbench when you're tasked with providing your own translations. [Per Salesforce's documentation on Platform Only languages](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=faq_getstart_what_languages_does.htm&type=0):

> In situations where Salesforce doesn’t provide default translations, use platform-only languages to localize apps and custom functionality that you’ve built on the Salesforce App Cloud. You can translate items such as custom labels, custom objects, and field names. You can also rename most standard objects, labels, and fields. Informational text and non-field label text aren’t translatable.
>
> Platform-only languages are available in all places where you can select a language in the application. However, when you select a platform-only language, all standard Salesforce labels default to English or, in select cases, to an end-user or fully supported language.